# How to prove that the date of a Word document was not tampered?

Tags: microsoft-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prove a file was not tampered?](https://superuser.com/questions/237396/how-to-prove-a-file-was-not-tampered)

I have uploaded the assignment on website before and  I didn't realize my file is not exist on the website until I found out that my assignment wasn't graded. My lecturer asked me to prove the date of my file which is my assignment is before the deadline and never be tampered.  I have the source files that show timestamps that are clearly before the deadline.  How to prove the date is reliable?

PS: I sent my assignment file which is as same as my source file to my classmate's laptop by a chat software in order to check the file was correct, and there is still the date of the file  in the chat software history list and i can still use the software of his laptop to receive and open the file again in his laptop.

Comment: Not really possible. Anything is editable, and there's no universal DRM you could use. Thank goodness!

Comment: Start using digital signatures in the future and sign all important data. Right now, there's no way to prove that dates are reliable.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: Don't forget that even digital signatures are based on the *signer's* timestamp, so a trusted timestamping service is needed.

Comment: One such trusted timestamping service is the lecturer's memory :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it now.

But to prove the existence of a document at a given date, you have to use a Timestamping authority that gives you a specific token of time for a specific file.

If you modify the document after that date, the token won't verify the document.

But you can't assess that a document existed before the date you use the service (and that's the point of the timestamping...)